# Is it good practice to show and hide view components in Layout of Android UI screen

Tags: android, user-interface

Currently, I am designing screen, where I need different buttons for different user types. But all the other UI components are same. Is it suggested to hide/show button while loading screen for a particular user or should I keep separate UI for separate user-type?

Comment: using the same screen is better, it keeps app size small

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obviously reuse the layout as you do in java but there are some things to keep in mind while reusing layout.

If your layout has a whole lot of view it is not advised because when the layout inflates all the UI  components inflates whether it is VISIBLE or GONE. So it totally depends on your use case.

My personal advice is you can use a different layout for different type of users because changing to the layout will be easier in the future. And it doesn't have a lot of effect on your app size.

I have seen apps like Myntra uses separate layouts. You can always decompile the apk and check their coding patterns

Answer (score 0):

If there's no so much difference just set button's visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, the same screen is fine as long as your doing validation checking. It's no different than html and designing 1 responsive page. In html the page loads faster using JavaScript , so that's why it's more efficient. In app design it could be more efficient if correctly laid out and grouped and enable and disable the parent box of the buttons.

Hope this helps!